# Combining Multiple Drop Down List Selections Into 1 Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, append

I have an order form that has 10 drop down lists where a user can select an item.  I am wanting to combine all the selected items into one variable separated by a comma.  The way I am doing it is using an if statement for each individual drop down list and adding to a string, is this the most efficient way to do such?  Here is a sub-set of my syntax (not all 10 drop down lists) but you will get the point:

```
string fullselection = null;

if (dropdownlist1.SelectedIndex > -1) { fullselection += dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Text; }
if (dropdownlist2.SelectedIndex > -1) { fullselection += "," + dropdownlist2.SelectedItem.Text; }
if (dropdownlist3.SelectedIndex > -1) { fullselection += "," + dropdownlist3.SelectedItem.Text; }
if (dropdownlist4.SelectedIndex > -1) { fullselection += "," + dropdownlist4.SelectedItem.Text; }
if (dropdownlist5.SelectedIndex > -1) { fullselection += "," + dropdownlist5.SelectedItem.Text; }
if (dropdownlist6.SelectedIndex > -1) { fullselection += "," + dropdownlist6.SelectedItem.Text; }
```

Comment: You can get list of dropdowns from page/form/Panel and use linq to do this.

Comment: Are the DropDownList databound ? If they are, are they bound to individual variables, or to a collection ?

Comment: @LucMorin the dropdownlists are bound to a list<listitem> that is created in the C# syntax (no database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work..

```
var ddlist = new List<DropdownList>();
ddlist.Add(dropdownlist1);//repeat this for all drowdowns.
var selectedTexts = ddlist.Where(x=>x.SelectedIndex > -1).Select(y=>y.SelectedItem.Text);
var fullselection = String.Join(",",selectedTexts.ToArray());
```